# Single machine with DHCP client on one network interface, and DHCP server on another?

Tags: linux, dhcp

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 running a version of Raspbian 7 (wheezy). These devices have an Ethernet RJ45 port (eth0), and a wireless WiFi module (wlan0). I would like to set them up as on this image:

[my-rpi3-network.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTovO.png)

Basically:

- I connect the Rpi3 via the wired eth0 to a switch, and I get Internet on it from another Ubuntu PC, which has Internet "Shared to other computers" on `eth0`, which makes the Ubuntu PC a DHCP server with address 10.42.0.1, assigning addresses to clients in the 10.42.0.X range. That is why I'd like to keep the `eth0` port on the Rpi3 as a DHCP client.
- I want to make the `wlan0` on the Rpi3 an access point - meaning that other machines could connect to it; I'm assuming this means that the Rpi3 must be a DHCP server on that interface, then (otherwise it would not be able to allocate a local IP to a client machine that had connected to it through WiFi).

So, I found this link: https://frillip.com/using-your-raspberry-pi-3-as-a-wifi-access-point-with-hostapd/ - and I was trying to follow it; first my Raspbian did not have `dhcpcd`, so I installed:

```
sudo apt-get install dhcpcd5
```

(it is `dhcpcd5` that has `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` - otherwise the `dhcpcd` package is actually `dhcpcd3` and it has `/etc/dhcpcd.sh` instead)

Midway through the tutorial I tried doing this as per instructions:

```
$ sudo service dhcpcd restart
[FAIL] Not running dhcpcd because /etc/network/interfaces ... failed!
[FAIL] defines some interfaces that will use a DHCP client ... failed!
```

My current `/etc/network/interfaces` is like this:

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
    address 172.24.1.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 172.24.1.0
    broadcast 172.24.1.255
#    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Other resources like https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/34914/wifi-not-working-on-startup mention that apparently the problem is that `/etc/network/interfaces` defines `eth0` to be a DHCP client:

> If you see this, then to correct, open a terminal:
>
> ```
> $ sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
> ```
>
> and replace dhcp with manual. The two lines from your interfaces are:
>
> ```
> iface eth0 inet manual
> iface default inet manual
> ```

However, I do not want to do this - because unless the `eth0` on the Rpi3 is a DHCP client, then I cannot get the Internet Sharing from the Ubuntu PC to work!

So, what I gather is that it is impossible to run a DHCP server on a machine that has one of its network interfaces defined as a DHCP client?! Is this true? Or to formulate it as a question:

- Can I have one network interface (`eth0`) as a DHCP client, and another (`wlan0`) as a DHCP server, on the same machine - and if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, instead of creating another DHCP server and subnet, I would just create a bridge in your RPi, which bridges the wireless and wired networks in the same network.

This way wireless clients get IP addresses directly from your Ubuntu server.

You can accomplish this with the following configuration in `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
bridge_ports wlan0 eth0

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual
```

`br0` will be the address of the bridge interface, which bridges `eth0` and `wlan0` interfaces together. Then we configure the interface to get IP address for the RPi via DHCP.

Using a bridge here instead of a another NAT layer prevents some issues that are caused by double-NAT.

Answer (score 0):

OP here - well at first I thought that the designation `manual` means the same as `static`, but that seems to not be the case; I found:

https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration

> To create a network interface without an IP address at all use the manual method and use pre-up and post-down commands to bring the interface up and down.
>
> ```
> iface eth0 inet manual
>    pre-up ifconfig $IFACE up
>    post-down ifconfig $IFACE down
> ```

... and so I copied those exact lines in `/etc/network/interfaces` (replacing the `iface eth0 inet dhcp`) - and it turned out, it works:

```
$ sudo service dhcpcd restart
dhcpcd[3253]: dhcpcd not running
dhcpcd[3254]: version 6.7.1 starting
dhcpcd[3254]: all: IPv6 kernel autoconf disabled
dhcpcd[3254]: eth0: adding address feXX::...
dhcpcd[3254]: if_addaddress6: Operation not supported
dhcpcd[3254]: DUID 00:XX:XX:...
dhcpcd[3254]: eth0: IAID eb:XX:....
dhcpcd[3254]: eth0: soliciting a DHCP lease
dhcpcd[3254]: eth0: offered 10.42.0.96 from 10.42.0.1
dhcpcd[3254]: eth0: leased 10.42.0.96 for 3600 seconds
dhcpcd[3254]: eth0: adding route to 10.42.0.0/24
dhcpcd[3254]: eth0: adding default route via 10.42.0.1
dhcpcd[3254]: forked to background, child pid 3307
```

So, as things work as expected (and they did so even after a reboot of the RPi3), I guess that is it, then...